# Django IntegerField returning long

Tags: python, django

I am wondering why, when I get a field from db which is defined as `models.IntegerField` in models.py I am getting `long` instead of `int` e.g. I have a model `EventSchedule`

```
class EventSchedule(models.Model):
    monthly_day = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    ...
```

in db it is

```
mysql> describe t_event_schedule;
+------------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field                  | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| monthly_day            | int(11)     | NO   |     | 1       |       |
...
```

but when I create an object, and retrieve back value from db it is `long`

```
>>> e = EventSchedule()
>>> e.monthly_day
1
>>> e.save()
>>> e2 = EventSchedule.objects.get(id=e.id)
>>> e2.monthly_day
1L
```

I am using

```
>>> django.VERSION
(1, 2, 1, 'final', 0
>>> platform.python_version()
'2.6.5
```

'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is probably a side effect of the underlying `dbapi` handler, which returns `long` for most everything:

```
>>> import MySQLdb
>>> db=MySQLdb.connect(db="test")
>>> c = db.cursor()
>>> c.execute("Select 1")
1L
```

The difference for most uses is cosmetic.  There are subtle differences from one driver to another, for instance `sqlite3` does *not* return long for this same query:

```
>>> import sqlite3
>>> db = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
>>> c = db.cursor()
>>> c.execute("Select 1")
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x7f2c425ae9d0>
>>> c.execute("Select 1").fetchone()
(1,)
```