# How to get ids using values_list python

Tags: python, django

I have the following django filter query:

```
ids = Worksheet.objects.filter(main=main_rec_id).values_list('id', flat=True)
```

But it return long values like `[5L, 6L]` how can I get a list like [5,6] guys? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Some explanation here: [django integer field returning long](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7733002/django-integerfield-returning-long)

Answer (score 2):

use this

```
ids = Worksheet.objects.filter(main=main_rec_id).values_list('id', flat=True)
ids = map(lambda x:int(x),ids)
```

ids will be pure integer LIST

Comment: map(lambda x:int(x),ids)

Comment: @Sayse: did my edited answer helped?

Comment: It produces the output the op is looking for, but its probably still not necessary. The suggested duplicates already provide an explanation.

Comment: when you fetch obj from db, by default id will be Long, there must me explicit type casting necessary. or while defining model class mention id=models.IntegerField(.....) could be the possible solution

Comment: this may give you possible ans http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-long-complex. If my post helped you out accept it :)

Answer (score 0):

[5L, 6L] has no effect for using as [5, 6], because 5L == 5.

Comment: `5L is 5` returns False. There *may* be side effects depending on what the op is doing.